# Monodromy of covering map related to symmetric group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X:=\mathbb{C}^n$, and let the symmetric group $S_n$ act by permutation of coordinates in the obvious way; let $X_n:=X/S_n$ be the quotient by the group action. Now, $X_n\simeq \mathbb{C}^n$, so we get a map $\pi: X\to X_n$ with finite fibers. Away from the discriminant $\Delta:=\prod_{i\lt j}(x_i-x_j)$, $\pi$ is a covering map $X\setminus\Delta\to X_n\setminus\pi(\Delta)$, and this map has monodromy group $S_n$. In similar fashion, we can let the subgroup $S_k$ act on the first $k$ coordinates, and let $X_k$ be the resulting quotient; again away from the discriminant the map $X\to X_k$ is a covering map and has monodromy group $S_k$. (We could of course generalise to $S_\lambda$ for a partition $\lambda$ of $n$, but let's keep it simple.)

Now, $\pi:X\to X_n$ factors through any of the $X_k$, so we have maps $X_k\to X_n$, and in particular $X_n\to X_{n+1}$, and away from the branching locus they are also covering maps.

> Question: What are the monodromy groups of these covering maps?

This seems like the sort of thing someone might have worked out long ago, is anything known about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $k=1,\dots,n-1$, the monodromy group of $q_k:X_k\to X_n$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_n$; one argument uses the fundamental theorem of Galois theory (or its analogue for topological covering spaces, if you prefer to work topologically).
First of all $q_1:X_1\to X_n$ equals $\pi$, which is a Galois cover with group of deck transformations $S_n$ by construction.  Next, for $k=1,\dots,n$, the morphism $q_k$ factors $\pi$, with the corresponding fixed subgroup being isomorphic to the copy of $S_k$ in $S_n$ that you indicated.  Hence also the Galois closure of $q_k$ factors $\pi$, with the corresponding fixed subgroup $N$ being the intersection of all conjugates of $S_k$, i.e., the largest normal subgroup of $S_n$ contained in $S_k$.  For $k=n$, $N$ equals $S_n$, so assume $k < n$.  For $n\geq 5$, of course, $S_n$ has only the normal subgroups $\{1\}$, $A_n$ and $S_n$, so $N$ equals $\{1\}$.  Also for $n=2,3,4$, it is straightforward to compute that $N$ equals $\{1\}$.  Thus $\pi$ is the Galois closure of $q_k$, and the Galois group $S_n/N$ equals $S_n$.